# How to grantee a open/download permission for an amazon s3 object in large bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an amazon bucket with hundreds of thousands of objects. I just uploaded new file using their AWS console, but I can't get it in their console as I must scroll down for thousand times!

I tried to make the folder public, but it loops over all objects. I also downloaded BucketExplorer, but it downloads the index of all objects which take much time!

So, is there anyway to edit the permission for a specific object on Amazon S3 remotely?!

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the objects again with the AWS CLI S3 and add the ACL in the options to public read. OR if that is not an option and you know the key of the new objects you can use the AWS CLI s3api command to edit the ACL with the s3api put-object-acl command.

## S3 cp Example

Copies test.txt file to the S3 bucket mybucket with the name of test2.txt and sets the ACL to public-read

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt --acl public-read
```

> --acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. If you use this parameter you must have the "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your IAM policy. Only accepts values of private, public-read, public-read-write, authenticated-read, aws-exec-read, bucket-owner-read, bucket-owner-full-control and log-delivery-write. See Canned ACL for details

## S3api Example

Sets the ACL to public read for objet file.txt in bucket MyBuckey

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket MyBucket --key file.txt --acl public-read
```

AWS CLI S3 CP command

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

AWS CLI s3api command

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into granting GetObject permissions via bucket policy?  The policy would apply to objects where the the bucket owner is also the object owner.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html